# Animated gif starting on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation, gif, animated-gif

I have made 4 animated gifs and i want them to start by the user's scroll.

What i did is use this:

```
$(function () {
    var screen = $(".screen");
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 1500) {
            screen.css('display','block');
        } else {
            screen.css('display','none');
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to display none and block the gifs by scroll and it works good, the problem is that the gif doesnt start from the beginning when i display block it, it starts from somewhere in the middle of the animation.

how can i make a gif start exactly from the first frame when i display block it?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You can't "restart" a gif, unless you refetch it from the server every time (you don't want that). One solution would be to use data-uris and re-apply the `src`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code does hide and show the images but it does not reload the image. Instead you should update your src attribute, or simple realod the same image.

```
$(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src"))

One simple solution would be 

if (scroll >= 1500) {
   screen.attr('src',screen.attr('src')); // update its src, this reloads the img
} else {
   screen.css('display','none');
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! that did it, just what should i add to the "else" so it will stop refreshing after 1500px scroll?